# Avoid scrolling content under fixed div

Tags: css

When a user clicks a button, a popup that covers the entire screen shows. This popup has scrollable content in it and is described as so :

```
   .popup{
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100000;
        opacity: 1;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
   }
```

However, the content beneath it is also scrollable so when i scroll to the bottom of the popup content, if i keep scrolling, the content underneath also scrolls.

Any way to avoid that?

Comment: Add this rule to the scroll content: `overflow:hidden;`, in your case do it by jQuery, on click add a class to the body with the rule I already told you